# Add a row to a Dojo 1.5 DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo

How do you add a row to a Dojo DataGrid, Dojo version 1.5? There apparently is no `newItem()` function in 1.5 which is the only answer I've found in my searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check kind of data store that you use. If you use [dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore) you can't add new items because it's read-only data store. Instead of dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore you should use [dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore). This data store will allow you to add (`store.newItem({}/*new item object*/)`), modify (`store.setValue(item, "name", newValue)`) and delete(`store.deleteItem(items)`) items.